# Am I coding and interpreting multiple Heaviside Functions correctly in a Cox model

Tags: r, survival

This is a long example, so be prepared....

I am  wondering if I am coding multiple Heaviside Functions correctly in a cox model using R. There are plenty examples of Using 2 heaviside functions but i cannot find good examples of 3 or more HS functions.

First off, we study seed germination, which means that "death" is actually germination of a seed and "survival" is a seed remaining un germinated.

The experimental design revolves around incubators going through a temperature change every 4 days starting at 32C and ending at 4C, and then there is a 8 day storage time at 20C. We have two treatments, 30-day and 60-day storage at 27.5C.
I wish to derive a hazard rate at each Temperature and compare the 30-day treatment to the control, and the 60-day treatment to the control. Obviously the control will be our baseline.

below I describe our current attempt.

Data can be found in link below

[https://www.dropbox.com/s/5etn1pbvifbfke1/S.O.testcode?dl=0][1]

subsequent code references data file as

`Pop0`

We measured germination every two days therefore we have interval data coded by Day1 and Day2. For example, on Day2 (our first observation) Day1=0 and Day2=2. The last observation was Day1=32 Day2=40.
Since temperatures were changed every 4 days, we wish to compare rates every 4 days. Therefore we create a new time variable that is measured every 4 days. However, for the last point, we wish to include 8 days not 4

```
for (i in 1:length(Pop0$Temp)){ 
                                ifelse(Pop0$Day1[i]==0,Pop0$NDay1[i]<-0,
        ifelse(Pop0$Day1[i]==2,Pop0$NDay1[i]<-0,
        ifelse(Pop0$Day1[i]==4,Pop0$NDay1[i]<-4,
        ifelse(Pop0$Day1[i]==6,Pop0$NDay1[i]<-4,
        ifelse(Pop0$Day1[i]==8,Pop0$NDay1[i]<-8,
        ifelse(Pop0$Day1[i]==10,Pop0$NDay1[i]<-8,
        ifelse(Pop0$Day1[i]==12,Pop0$NDay1[i]<-12,
        ifelse(Pop0$Day1[i]==14,Pop0$NDay1[i]<-12,
        ifelse(Pop0$Day1[i]==16,Pop0$NDay1[i]<-16,
        ifelse(Pop0$Day1[i]==18,Pop0$NDay1[i]<-16,
        ifelse(Pop0$Day1[i]==20,Pop0$NDay1[i]<-20,
        ifelse(Pop0$Day1[i]==22,Pop0$NDay1[i]<-20,
        ifelse(Pop0$Day1[i]==24,Pop0$NDay1[i]<-24,
        ifelse(Pop0$Day1[i]==26,Pop0$NDay1[i]<-24,
        ifelse(Pop0$Day1[i]==28,Pop0$NDay1[i]<-28,
        ifelse(Pop0$Day1[i]==30,Pop0$NDay1[i <-28,Pop0$NDay1[i]<-32))))))))))))))))

                            }


for (i in 1:length(Pop0$NDay1)){ 
         ifelse(Pop0$NDay1[i]==32,Pop0$NDay2[i]<-40,Pop0$NDay2[i]<-Pop0$NDay1[i]+4)}`
```

Now we create cut points for our Heaviside Functions

```
pops.cph30=survSplit(Pop0,cut=c(4,8,12,16,20,24,28,32),end="Day2",event="Event",start="Day1")

pops.cph30$hv1TD3032=pops.cph30$TD30C*(pops.cph30$Day1<=2) 
    pops.cph30$hv2TD3028=pops.cph30$TD30C*(pops.cph30$Day1>2&pops.cph30$Day1<=6) 
    pops.cph30$hv3TD3024=pops.cph30$TD30C*(pops.cph30$Day1>6&pops.cph30$Day1<=10) 
    pops.cph30$hv4TD3020=pops.cph30$TD30C*(pops.cph30$Day1>10&pops.cph30$Day1<=14) 
    pops.cph30$hv5TD3016=pops.cph30$TD30C*(pops.cph30$Day1>14&pops.cph30$Day1<=18) 
    pops.cph30$hv6TD3012=pops.cph30$TD30C*(pops.cph30$Day1>18&pops.cph30$Day1<=22) 
    pops.cph30$hv7TD308=pops.cph30$TD30C*(pops.cph30$Day1>22&pops.cph30$Day1<=26) 
    pops.cph30$hv8TD304=pops.cph30$TD30C*(pops.cph30$Day1>26&pops.cph30$Day1<=30) 
    pops.cph30$hv9TD3020=pops.cph30$TD30C*(pops.cph30$Day1>30)
```

Define Surv object and Cox model

```
Y30=Surv(pops.cph30$Day1,pops.cph30$Day2, pops.cph30$Event)
k<-coxph(Y30 ~hv1TD3032+hv2TD3028+hv3TD3024+hv4TD3020+hv5TD3016+hv6TD3012+hv7TD308
+hv8TD304+hv9TD3020+cluster(Rep), data=pops.cph30)

summary(k)
```

Print Summary with all Heaviside Functions

```
Call:

coxph(formula = Y30 ~ hv1TD3032 + hv2TD3028 + hv3TD3024 + hv4TD3020 + 
hv5TD3016 + hv6TD3012 + hv7TD308 + hv8TD304 + hv9TD3020 + 
cluster(Rep), data = pops.cph30)

n= 5328, number of events= 160 

         coef exp(coef) se(coef) robust se      z Pr(>|z|)  
hv1TD3032      NA        NA   0.0000    0.0000     NA       NA  
hv2TD3028      NA        NA   0.0000    0.0000     NA       NA  
hv3TD3024      NA        NA   0.0000    0.0000     NA       NA  
hv4TD3020  0.8981    2.4548   0.6455    0.6230  1.442   0.1494  
hv5TD3016  0.4108    1.5081   0.4454    0.4871  0.844   0.3989  
hv6TD3012  0.4367    1.5475   0.4454    0.4379  0.997   0.3187  
hv7TD308   0.3216    1.3793   0.5774    0.2828  1.137   0.2556  
hv8TD304  -0.2008    0.8181   0.6325    0.2663 -0.754   0.4507  
hv9TD3020  0.5899    1.8039   0.2720    0.2656  2.221   0.0263 *

Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

      exp(coef) exp(-coef) lower .95 upper .95
hv1TD3032        NA         NA        NA        NA
hv2TD3028        NA         NA        NA        NA
hv3TD3024        NA         NA        NA        NA
hv4TD3020    2.4548     0.4074    0.7240     8.324
hv5TD3016    1.5081     0.6631    0.5806     3.917
hv6TD3012    1.5475     0.6462    0.6559     3.651
hv7TD308     1.3793     0.7250    0.7923     2.401
hv8TD304     0.8181     1.2224    0.4854     1.379
hv9TD3020    1.8039     0.5544    1.0719     3.036

Concordance= 0.547  (se = 0.018 )
Rsquare= 0.002   (max possible= 0.284 )
Likelihood ratio test= 8.16  on 6 df,   p=0.2268
Wald test            = 17.12  on 6 df,   p=0.008842
Score (logrank) test = 9.17  on 6 df,   p=0.1645,   Robust = 3.74  p=0.7111

(Note: the likelihood ratio and score tests assume independence of
 observations within a cluster, the Wald and robust score tests do not).
```

My questions is about the interpretation of the hazard ratios in the output for a particular Heaviside function. 
Would I be correct in interpreting that the Proportional hazard assumption is violated for Heaviside function 9 (hv9TD3020? Therefore I could conclude that the germination rates at that temperature (20C) after 30 days is larger than that of the control (baseline).

All other heaviside functions are also larger for 30 day stored seeds, except for at temp 4C (hv8TD304), However the differences are not statistically different.

here is a plot of the data

```
surv.time<-survfit(Surv(NDay1,NDay2,Event)~TD30C,data=Pop0)
c<-1-surv.time$surv[1:10]*100
    cu<-(1-surv.time$upper[1:10]*100)-c
cl<-1-surv.time$lower[1:10]*100-c
    c1a<-1-surv.time$surv[11:20]*100-c
c1u<-1-surv.time$upper[11:20]*100-c
    c1l<-1-surv.time$lower[11:20]*100-c


plot(c(0,0,0)~c(0,16,40),xlim=c(0,40),xaxt='n',yaxt='n', ylim =        c(-60,60),type="l",lwd=2,lty=1,col="black",ylab="Difference in Percent Germination",xlab="Days")
cord<-cbind(c(surv.time$time[1:10],rev(surv.time$time[1:10])),c(cu,rev(cl)))
polygon(cord[,1],cord[,2],col="grey40",lty=2)

cord1<-cbind(c(surv.time$time[11:20],rev(surv.time$time[11:20])),c(c1u,rev(c1l)))
polygon(cord1[,1],cord1[,2],col="grey92",lty=2)

lines(c1a~surv.time$time[11:20],lwd=1,lty=1,col="black")
    points(c1a~surv.time$time[11:20],pch=21,bg="white",col="black")
lines(c(0,0),c(-35,60),lty=3)
lines(c(4,4),c(-35,60),lty=3)
lines(c(8,8),c(-35,60),lty=3)
lines(c(12,12),c(-35,60),lty=3)
lines(c(16,16),c(-35,60),lty=3)
lines(c(20,20),c(-60,60),lty=3)
lines(c(24,24),c(-60,60),lty=3)
lines(c(28,28),c(-60,60),lty=3)
lines(c(32,32),c(-60,60),lty=3)
lines(c(40,40),c(-60,60),lty=3)

legend("bottomleft", y = NULL,"30 Days 5°C",pch=21,lwd=1,cex=1.2)

 axis(3,par(mgp=c(0,-1.5,0)),at=c(2,6,10,14,18,22,26,30,36),labels=c("32°C","28°C","24°C","20 °C","16°C","12°C","8°C","4°C","20°C"),tick=FALSE)

axis(2,par(mgp=c(-0,1,0)),at=c(-60,-40,-20,0,20,40,60),labels=c("60٪","40٪","20٪","0٪","20٪","40٪","60٪"))

axis(1,at=c(0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40),labels=c("0","5","10","15","20","25","30","35","40"))
```

Is there a way for me to improve my question? 
I assume the heaviside functions are not used frequently.
I base my code on the published work of Kleinbaum and Klein. The "Backmatter" has good examples of code.

-Michael

Comment: My only comment for getting more attention is that your example is quite long. It would be much more approachable if you pared it down to an example with, say, 10-20 rows of data with 1 predictor and 1 or 2 heaviside functions. You could then share the data with `dput` so we don't have to download and read in data, and you could show the `head` of the data at each step of the way so we don't have to run the code and poke around to see what's going on.

Comment: Thanks, I understand your concern. Unfortunately I think that using one or two Heaviside functions misses the point of my question (There are published examples using two Heaviside functions). What I can't find, are examples using three or more Heaviside functions. I will try to make a condensed dataset nonetheless.

Comment: I think I have an answer. Will post soon.